# Type determination when indexing on non-array pointers & reading beyond the last element

Tags: c++, pointers, indexing

```
int main()
{
    auto foo = new int;
}
```

I understand that foo will be of type int*.
Since foo is a pointer you can index it with [].
Therefore foo[0] will be the same as *foo and be of type int.

What I'm having trouble with understanding is why foo[1] would be an int.
I know c++ doesn't care that you go 'out of bounds' and undefined behavior is expected, but why would foo[1] also be of type int?
Does it just takes the next 4 bytes and assumes it is an int because foo is an int*?

Comment: `foo` can be seen as a pointer to the first element of a one-element array. It's similar to e.g. `int array[1]; int* foo = &array[0];`. However, C++ doesn't have any kinds of bounds checking for array or pointers. Therefore you can easily access elements out of bounds, like `foo[1]`. This will lead to *undefined behavior*. But even when going out of bounds, the "base type" will still be the same, as each element in the "array" is the same type.

Comment: If `foo` is declared as a pointer type (e.g. `int*`), then the expression `foo[x]` is interpreted as `*(foo + x)`. It doesn't matter what value of `x` is. `foo + x` may point to a valid memory location, or it may not. It's up to you, to not use invalid values of `x`. Interestingly, this makes expressions, such as `x[foo]` work, due to them being interpreted as `*(x + foo)`, which is exactly the same as `*(foo + x)`.

Comment: "foo will be of type int*." Note that this means `foo` might point at one `int`, or many `int` in an array, or no `int` at all. They're all the same type. This is important for understanding `foo[1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this expression

```
foo[1]
```

there is used the pointer arithmetic. This expression is evaluated like

```
*( foo + 1 )
```

The sub-expression `foo + 1` has the type `int *` . So formally the full expression has the type `int`. That is the memory pointed to by the sub-expression `foo + 1` is interpreted as storing an object of the type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it just takes the next 4 bytes and assumes it is an int because foo is an int*?

I would say that's an easy way to look at it.

Fundamentally C++'s type system is fixed at compile-time. Putting aside things like virtual functions or dynamic_cast, C++ doesn't verify or second-guess what type it's told to treat memory as. When you get down to basic types like `int`, they don't carry any meta-information from which one could determine whether a certain 4 bytes in memory are an `int` or a `float` or `char[4]` or something else.

So, for example, the memory pointed to by an is `int*` is treated as an `int`. Under the hood in the instructions that make up a compiled program, this is a very simple and efficient way for things to work.

This also leads to the all the advice to be cautious about casting from one type to another, and generally avoid it if possible. Because with casting you can force memory to be treated as a different type than it normally would be - essentially telling the compiler "do what I say because I know better than you". If you know what you're doing, this can be used for clever tricks. But if you're mistaken, then nothing is going to save you from shooting yourself in the foot.